# how to iterate over a list in a column in pandas to find a match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, match

I have a list of terms and would like to find whether there is a match for the particular word

| meta |
| --- |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'cake'] |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'Biscuit', 'Oreo'] |

I'm trying to find a match from this list:
list of terms = ['cake', 'biscuit']

expected Output:

| meta | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'cake'] | True |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'Biscuit', 'Oreo'] | True |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `set` [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
terms = {'cake', 'biscuit'}

df['Column B'] = [bool(set(x)&terms) for x in df['meta']]
```

If case doesn't matter (for example `'Biscuit'`/`'biscuit'`), make your strings lowercase with [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) (or [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)):

```
df['Column B'] = [bool(set(map(str.lower, x))&terms) for x in df['meta']]
```

Output:

```
                             meta  Column B
0           [Home, grocery, cake]      True
1  [Home, grocery, Biscuit, Oreo]      True
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert list to sets and use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) in list comprehension with convert values of lists to lowercase:

```
terms = ['cake', 'biscuit']
S = set(terms)

df['Column B'] = [not set(y.lower() for y in x).isdisjoint(S) for x in df['meta']]
```

---

```
df['Column B'] = [not set(map(str.lower, x)).isdisjoint(S) for x in df['meta']]
print (df)
                             meta  Column B
0           [Home, grocery, cake]      True
1  [Home, grocery, Biscuit, Oreo]      True
```

because not matach `Biscuit`:

```
df['Column B'] = [not set(x).isdisjoint(S) for x in df['meta']]
print (df)
                             meta  Column B
0           [Home, grocery, cake]      True
1  [Home, grocery, Biscuit, Oreo]     False
```