# How to Get the match value in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I would like to compare a list in a pandas column with another normal list and find the match value and put it in another column.

I have a list of terms and would like to find whether there is a match for the particular word

| meta |
| --- |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'cake'] |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'Biscuit', 'Oreo'] |

I'm trying to find a match from this list:
terms = ['cake', 'biscuit']

expected Output:

| meta | result | match value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'cake'] | True | ['cake'] |
| ['Home', 'grocery', 'Biscuit', 'Oreo'] | True | ['biscuit'] |

PS: I'm looking how to get the **match value** column

Comment: Replace `bool` by `list` in *@mozway's* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75984581/16120011) to make the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex pattern to extract substring after explode your lists:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(terms)})", re.IGNORECASE)

df['match value'] = (df['meta'].explode().str.extractall(pattern)[0]
                               .groupby(level=0).agg(list)

df['result'] = df['match value'].str.len().astype(bool)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                             meta   match value  result
0  [Home, grocery, cake, biscuit]        [cake]    True
1  [Home, grocery, Biscuit, Oreo]     [Biscuit]    True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"meta": ['Home', 'grocery', 'cake']},
    {"meta": ['Home', 'grocery', 'Biscuit', 'Oreo']}
    ])

terms = ['cake', 'biscuit']

df["match_value"] = df["meta"].apply(lambda row: list(set(map(str.lower, row)).intersection(set(terms))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We use explode with vectorized string matching

```
exploded = df['meta'].explode().str.lower()
df['match'] = exploded[exploded.isin(terms)].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df['result'] = df['match'].str.len() > 0
```

For best results, ensure the terms in `terms` are lowercased as well.

---

Let's try another set of terms to see how this works

```
terms = ['home', 'biscuit']

exploded = df['meta'].explode().str.lower()
df['match'] = exploded[exploded.isin(terms)].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df['result'] = df['match'].str.len() > 0
df
    
                             meta            match  result
0           [Home, grocery, cake]           [home]    True
1  [Home, grocery, Biscuit, Oreo]  [home, biscuit]    True
```