# How to iterate over a pandas column with a Nan values present in the data set? (note: I cannot drop the nan rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, exception

I'm trying to perform a match function in pandas column with a list named metalist and it is showing an error "expected a string or a buffer".

| Meta |
| --- |
| [Home, Grocery, Cake] |
| [Home, Grocery, Biscuit] |
| Nan |
| [Home, Grocery, Apple] |

metalist = ['Apple', 'Cake', 'Biscuit']

my expected output is:

| Meta | Available |
| --- | --- |
| [Home, Grocery, Cake] | true |
| [Home, Grocery, Biscuit] | true |
| Nan | False |
| [Home, Grocery, Apple] | true |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to iterate over a list in a column in pandas to find a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75984556/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-a-column-in-pandas-to-find-a-match)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use boolean indexing. Also, convert the `metalist` from list to set to speed up the search:

```py
metalist = ['Apple', 'Cake', 'Biscuit']

mask = df['Meta'].notna()
metalist = set(metalist)
df.loc[~mask, 'Available'] = False
df.loc[mask, 'Available'] = df.loc[mask, 'Meta'].apply(lambda x: bool(metalist.intersection(x)))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       Meta Available
0     [Home, Grocery, Cake]      True
1  [Home, Grocery, Biscuit]      True
2                       NaN     False
3    [Home, Grocery, Apple]      True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple conditional and set operations:

```
S = set(metalist)

df['Available'] = [isinstance(x, list) and bool(S.intersection(x))
                   for x in df['Meta']]
```

Alternative with a custom function:

```
def overlap(s1, s2):
    try:
        return not s1.isdisjoint(s2)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    
S = set(metalist)

df['Available'] = [overlap(S, x) for x in df['Meta']]
```

Output:

```
                       Meta  Available
0     [Home, Grocery, Cake]       True
1  [Home, Grocery, Biscuit]       True
2                       NaN      False
3    [Home, Grocery, Apple]       True
```